# Trying to merge pdf files in node: PDFUnite + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, heroku

I have a site on heroku, and am using the HyPDF addon which allows you to manipulate pdf's in a number ways.  Specifically, I am trying to merge two pdf's that I have the URL's for.

However, it's not working. I am using request to pull the pdf files and then using request to make the call to PDFUnite. It's a bit of callback hell too, so if you have any suggestions on how to fix that, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
request({url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=4010e80d-9106-4824-95ab-799ec81c7fd0', encoding: null}, function(err, res, body) {
var pdf1 = body;

    request({url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=28a388c6-ca0e-45a1-9aaf-9b6688c5a557', encoding: null}, function(err2, res2, body2){
        var pdf2 = body2;

        request.post(
        'https://www.hypdf.com/htmltopdf',
        {
        json: {
            user: HY_USER,
            password: HY_PASS,
            file_1: pdf1,
            file_2: pdf2
        }
        },
        function (error3, res3, body3) {

          if (!error && res2.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('Public URL: ', body3.url);
            console.log('Number of pages: ', res3.headers['hypdf-pages']);
          }
        });
    })
});
```

/****************UDPATED*****************/

I've updated the code, using https://gist.github.com/redfield/6724717 as a guide.  The difference is that code sample uses files, whereas I'm using a URL.

I've tried to modify it appropriately, but obviously something is off...If I use body or body.toString('base64') as the pdf1 and pdf2 then I get a 400 status error.  Otherwise, if I use the res as the pdf files, then I get a 504 error.  I'm not really sure how I should be sending in the files, so it's just guess and check.  Appreciate the help!

```
request({url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=4010e80d-9106-4824-95ab-799ec81c7fd0', encoding: null}, function(err, res, body) {
    var pdf1 = body;

        request({url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=28a388c6-ca0e-45a1-9aaf-9b6688c5a557', encoding: null}, function(err2, res2, body2){
            var pdf2 = body2;

            var form = new FormData();
            form.append('user', HYPDF_USER);
            form.append('password', HYPDF_PASSWORD);
            form.append('test', 'true');
            // form.append('bucket', 'hypdf_test');
            form.append('key', 'hypdf_test.pdf');
            form.append('public', 'true');
            form.append('file1', pdf1);
            form.append('file2', pdf2);

            form.submit('https://www.hypdf.com/pdfunite', function(err, res) {
                console.log('err ', err);
                // res – response object (http.IncomingMessage)
                console.log(res.statusCode, res.resume());
            });         
        })
    });
```

UPDATE #2
I've updated the code combining my code with @remus' code below.  However, I'm still getting an error - "Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null" on the request.post line.  Any thoughts?

```
request({url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=4010e80d-9106-4824-95ab-799ec81c7fd0', encoding: null}, function(err, res, body) {
  var pdf1 = body.toString('base64');

    request({url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=28a388c6-ca0e-45a1-9aaf-9b6688c5a557', encoding: null}, function(err2, res2, body2){
        var pdf2 = body2.toString('base64');

        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('user', HY_UN);
        form.append('password', HY_PASS);
        form.append('public', 'true');
        form.append('file1', fs.createReadStream(pdf1));
        form.append('file2', fs.createReadStream(pdf1));

        request.post({
          url: 'https://www.hypdf.com/pdfunite', 
          formData: form
        }, function(e, r, body) {
          // body should be the binary result of the merged .pdf
          console.log('e', e);
          console.log('body', body);
        });

      })
  });
```

UPDATE 3

ERROR STACK for the request.post - I've tried a number of things, can't get rid of it.  Any thoughts?

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null
    at appendFormValue (/node_modules/request/request.js:340:17)
    at Request.init (/node_modules/request/request.js:354:11)
    at new Request (/node_modules/request/request.js:140:8)
    at request (/node_modules/request/index.js:55:10)
    at Function.post (/node_modules/request/index.js:63:12)
    **at Request._callback (/server/api/emailInvoice/emailInvoice.controller.js:34:12)**
    at Request.self.callback (/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/node_modules/request/request.js:1073:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/node_modules/request/request.js:1019:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:929:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the main problem is you're trying to POST binary data (.pdf) as JSON in your last POST request. I imagine that's not going to work - like maybe it expects multipart file data? Second, an easy way to fix up your callback hell is to use [node-async](/questions/tagged/node-async):

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

async.parallel(function(callback) {
    pdf1: function(callback) {
        request.get({
            url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=4010e80d-9106-4824-95ab-799ec81c7fd0'
        }, function(err, r, body) {
            callback(err, body);
        });
    },
    pdf2: function(callback) {
        request.get({
            url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=28a388c6-ca0e-45a1-9aaf-9b6688c5a557'
        }, function(err, r, body) {
            callback(err, body);
        });
    },
    function(err, results) {
        var formData = {
            user: HY_USER,
            password: HY_PASS,
            file_1: fs.createReadStream(results.pdf1),
            file_2: fs.createReadStream(results.pdf2)
        }
        request.post({
            url: 'https://www.hypdf.com/pdfunite',
            formData: formData
        }, function(e, r, body) {
            // body should be the binary result of the merged .pdf
        });
    });
});
```

Notice both the `fs.createReadStream` from the binary data stream, and the proper url using [`pdfunite`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/hypdf#pdfunite).

You might also want to check out the [`hypdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hypdf) NPM module - I didn't test it out, but it might make things even easier than manually building up the request.

****UPDATE****

The problem was with using FormData().  For some reason, request.post didn't like it.  I was also able to remove the callbacks by injecting the request streams directly into the form.  Also note, you have to set encoding to null.

```
    var finalpdf;
    var formData = {
        'user': HY_USER,
        'password': HY_PASSWORD,
        'test': 'true',
        'public': 'true',
        'file1': request({url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=4010e80d-9106-4824-95ab-799ec81c7fd0', encoding: null}),
        'file2': request({url: 'http://www.sesamestreet.org/cms_services/services?action=download&uid=28a388c6-ca0e-45a1-9aaf-9b6688c5a557', encoding: null})
    }


    request.post({url: 'https://www.hypdf.com/pdfunite', encoding: null,     formData: formData}, function(err, res3, body3){
       finalPdf = body3.toString('base64');
});
```

Comment: Thanks remus!  You're right.  Let me change it around and see if it works.  Have a good dinner!

Comment: Ok, still not working, but you can see my changes in the update.

Comment: Think that'll do - give it a shot

Comment: Hey @remus, I had got my code working with the form.submit(), but I don't get a body variable that way.  So I combined your request.post() with my code and it should work, but I'm getting an odd error regarding hasOwnProperty on null.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace in your q?

Comment: Hm also if you're base64-encoding the binary file, you probably don't need to also do fs.createReadStream. BUT, if I'm wrong, you might need to base64 encode the read stream itself (fs.createReadStream(pdf1).toString('base64')) - you'll have to play around with that.

Comment: Posted....I tried a number of things for what I was sending in but it wasn't changing the error.  There's something about that request.post that it doesn't like.

Comment: Ugh, I dunno. What about trying that module I mentioned?